# How to Store Multi-Dimensional Array in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I am trying to store a multi dimensional (2 dimension) array in JavaScript phonegap using localstorage.setitem

However, it seems to convert the array into a single dimension.

Is there any way to maintain the array structure when stored locally?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and I used the following solution to make it work:

```
var a1 = [1,2,3];
var b1 = [4,5,6];
var c1 = [7,8,9];
var a = [a1, b1, c1];
localStorage.setItem("arr", JSON.stringify(a));
var b = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("arr"));
```

By default, localStorage only supports strings as storage formats. You can’t store results of JavaScript computations that are arrays or objects, and every number is stored as a string - http://24ways.org/2010/html5-local-storage.
​